# GXT NumberField / TextField align right

Tags: gwt, gxt

Is there a clean way to align the digits of a NumberField to the right?

I found [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153451-Text-Field-Aligning-text-with-right-alignment-for-a-number-type-content) which suggests an answer in GXT 2 :

```
this .setInputStyleAttribute("text-align", "right");
```

But it does not work in GXT 3 and I did not find any equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it with some CSS.

After looking at the generated HTML of a NumberField, it was something like

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ...>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I finally defined this css property

```
.numberField input{
  text-align : right;
}
```

and applied it on all my NumberFields.

Answer (score 0):

Try `textField.setDirection(Direction.RTL);`